# how to update arraylist in mysql database in android

Tags: php, mysql, arraylist

i am passing two arraylist from android to php using url .if the table(test) contains only one column(menuname) means update properly. if i am add another column to table(test) as like menuimage means in first row of column(menuname) is updated other rows are not updated properly.

```
<?php
    $old_menu_names=explode(',',preg_replace('/^.*\[(.*)\].*$/','$1',trim($_POST['menuname'], '[]')));
    $new_menu_names=explode(',',preg_replace('/^.*\[(.*)\].*$/','$1',trim($_POST['editmainmenu'], '[]')));
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "MobixMySQL");
    mysql_select_db("cozydine");
    foreach ($old_menu_names as $key => $old_name) {
        $new_name = mysql_real_escape_string($new_menu_names[$key]);
        $old_name  = mysql_real_escape_string($old_menu_names[$key]);
        echo $new_name;
        mysql_query("UPDATE `mainmenu` SET `menuname` = '$new_name' WHERE menuname = '$old_name'")
        or die('Error' . mysql_error());
        echo "Updated";
    }
?>
```

if the table having two columns means first row only updated remaing rows are not updated ..

Comment: Why dont you send array tp php as json ?

Comment: ya . i don't know how to send namevalue pairs in json.. that why i send array list. if table having one column means working properly. if table having more than one column means update only first row..

Answer (score 0):

```
In java you can send name value pair like this
 JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
 object.put("name","value");

 and import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

 and send the object.
 and in php version heigher than 5 you can get the values using json_decode() function

 json_decode($object);


 Hope this will help.
```